# FAQ links to itself

Tags: discussion, site-faq

If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close, you get

> **not constructive**
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) for guidance.

which links to https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close itself. Can't the link go to something with more than one paragraph on what's meant by "not constructive", and why they aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Funny thing about /faq#close is not only that it provides no further info than repeating the close notifications, but that it also links to itself four times. Recursive madness is recursive madness is...

Comment: [Did you mean: Recursion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137012/faq-links-to-itself#comment383162_137012)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Close Reasons should link to “How to Ask,” not to the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134520/close-reasons-should-link-to-how-to-ask-not-to-the-faq)

Answer (score 6):

Some might argue that the links were designed to just refer back to the master FAQ; however, the section on `on-topic` questions is even more misleading.

The section that says:

> Read more about [closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) here.

is even more misleading, as it explicitly suggests that it links to some detailed information, yet it just loops you back to the top.

In my opinion, there is some housecleaning that could be done here to make this less confusing. Perhaps the SE team could link to [I Move to Close This Question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/) or [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) or something that goes into more detail than a circular reference.

Answer (score 5):

I was about to ask this, it's still present now, extremely confusing and the links adds no value.

Why not link it to [What is a "closed" or “on hold” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question) rather than have the circular link:

[image: See the faq recursion]