# Show banner in edited closed questions asking for reopen review

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

Getting a question reopened is very, very hard. This is in part because the system doesn't encourage us to review edited questions. If I open a question and I see that five users who I know and trust have voted to close it, there is a huge discussion in the comments underneath, and there are some downvotes, there is little incentive for me to actually *look* at the question and judge whether it should be reopened: It's already taken care of by my peers. Of course, in an ideal world, I would to look independently at every question with my own eyes, but it just doesn't always happen.

There are the reopen queues now that help get questions reopened and that's cool; still, now that we're [reworking close messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732) and possibly explicitly promising OPs that their questions actually have a chance of getting reopened, can we do them a favour and show a banner:

> ## This question has been edited since it was closed.
>
> Please review whether the problems that lead to its closing have been fixed by the edit. If they have, consider casting a reopen vote. If they haven't, no need to do anything.

or to prevent blind reopen voting:

> ## This question *may* deserve reopening.
>
> Please review whether the problems that lead to its closing have been fixed by the recent edit. If they have, consider casting a reopen vote. If they haven't, no need to do anything.

under the following conditions:

- If a question has been edited substantially after closing
- If one reopen vote has been cast already* (by someone other than the OP)
- to users with reopen powers

<sub>*this would prevent the banner from showing up on *every* question that got some minor edit. The limitation *may* not be necessary at all, one would have to see</sub>

Comment: Are closers/reopeners going to garner any reputation from these actions?

Comment: Aren't questions edited after being close added to the reopen queue already? I am more concerned with questions wrongly closed, or edit made just before the question is closed.

Comment: @nhahtdh they do go to the reopen queue, but I'm sure there's still plenty of traffic coming to these questions the "normal" way. Mike - not as a result of this suggestion, no

Comment: @mikeb there are badges for the review tasks.

Comment: Why would we get rep from closing or reopening?

Comment: Did you mean "if one reopen vote has been cast already"?

Comment: @Michael oh, yeah, of course. Fixed, thanks

Comment: How long should the banner be there?

Comment: @sixlettervariables Because http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions. If people can get reputation for correcting a typo, I don't think it's out of line to expect the same reward for for helping people find better quality questions/answers than their own.

Comment: @nhahtdh potentially for ever - although there may be reasons to limit it. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: @Pekka웃: Different from most of the banners (duplicate, closed, locked), which are informative, the banner you suggest is inviting people to take action. I think placing it there long enough may invite people to blindly reopen the question.

Comment: @nha fair point. Maybe we need different wording? `This question **may** be eligible for reopening.`

Comment: Bullet two: If one reopen vote has been cast already _by someone other than the OP_. I could count on one hand the closed questions I've seen from a user >3k without a reopen vote.

Comment: @Josh oh, yeah, absolutely. You can vote to reopen your own questions? Wow.

Comment: @MikeB: I think it is bizarre we hand out rep for editing, but that's just me.

Comment: @Pekka웃: Wording is not the point I'm making. The problem is the duration of the banner. There should be some mechanism to take down the banner, rather than putting it there forever.

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah, fair point. Maybe it should go away after X views? On the permise that if x people saw the banner but didn't do anything, it's probably worth keeping closed

Comment: @Pekka웃: I'm also thinking along those line. Something like X views by 3k+ users, or expire after d days without action(s) or a combination of both. However, is there statistic about the number of views after the question is edited? I'd expect that if a question gets closed, it will hardly get any attention from people, aside from the review queue.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good suggestion. However it's not enough.

### Other things to consider

- Expand the reopen queue. The current queue is incredibly narrow (only closed questions edited **by the OP**, **no more than 5 days since it was closed**). Expand it to include any edits to a closed question.
- Make bumped closed questions last longer on the top of the home page. I don't see many closed question in my interesting questions stream, which is a shame. Present an edited closed question for more time at the top of the steam, to give it more chances of being reviewed.

Comment: These would probably make good feature requests in themselves. Another idea: show review candidates on the home page as `[review]` (or `[closed, edited]` or something like that) instead of `[closed]` which is a turn-off to click on them in the first place