# Does this question deserve closing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, close-reasons

I am here trying to understand why https://stackoverflow.com/q/15823425 was closed. I am not contesting, but SE rules tend to go over my head, and as [Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171732) has shown, the NC close reason could be clearer. If I were to choose, I would close the question as a shopping recommendation, but then what if there isn't even such an item in the store (as I think is the case with that particular question)?

Comment: Kudos for posting a question seeking knowledge, rather than ranting. Questions like this also tend to get wrongly-closed questions reopened.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Essentially, any question asking for resources (books, links, libraries) and that is just too general (no real constraints) it a shopping question and the answers would end up be subjective.

At the moment, "Not Constructive" is also for shopping questions.

Additionally, as a deleted comment noted, the second paragraph of the question is inviting discussion - something we specifically do not want.