# Why was my question closed as not constructive?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question: [Can HTML5 games be wrapped in SWF files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376534/can-html5-games-be-wrapped-in-swf-files) was closed earlier, as 'not constructive'.

I was asking what seemed to be a legitimate question relating to a tool that might be able to package an HTML5 game/webapp into a SWF file for easy access.

To clarify, my question was about **any** HTML5 application, not just games, and how they could be packaged for desktop/browser usage via a SWF file.

What may have resulted in my question being closed, other than going in the reverse direction of what's typically asked (SWF->HTML5)?

Comment: Your question doesn't have a constructive answer.  Nobody ever likes to carefully document and prove that something is impossible.  It is therefore easier to consider the question unconstructive.

Comment: It's that hard to conceive a pseudo-webserver that contains all your assets and presents them via the Flash VM while avoiding server costs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)

Comment: @gnat I don't see how this is a duplicate. It addresses a different point entirely

Comment: This type of question is also known as a "shopping question".  We routinely shut these down as they are answered by links which rot (in a few years from now, they're worthless) and attract spam (which you won't notice as we routinely destroy spammers, but excuse us if we don't want more work, thanks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question was closed as "not constructive":

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, **polling**, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Emphasis mine.

This closure reason has problems - one of the biggest is its wording: [that's being fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv). One of the main uses of *not constructive* isn't obvious from reading the text. Questions asking for software recommendations are generally closed as NC.

You asked:

> Is there any project capable of wrapping my pages and scripts into a swf?

Where the only reasonable response is a list of such projects. That was a common response at the dawn of the network, and it didn't work out well. Lists go out of date. Debates break out - Foo is better than Bar. So, [this happened](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and the rules were tightened.

You might have a better shot if you provide more detail. You don't have much right now. Review what tools you've tried, and why the Frobnitz project, which every right-thinking developer *knows* is the right tool for the job, won't work for you because of specific reasons A and B and C. Review the blog post I linked to. Give more to bite into.

Comment: I've made an edit to the question to change it from *"Is there a resource to do X"* to *"How can I do X"*, and have voted to reopen it.