# Can we be more specific as to why a question is "NARQ?"

Tags: discussion, not-a-real-question

Not a real question (NARQ) is a "broad" category that encompasses the following:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Can we specify *which* form of "NARQ" the question falls under by saying

1. NARQ--ambiguous
2. NARQ---vague
3. NARQ--incomplete
4. NARQ--overly broad
5. NARQ--rhetorical

so that the OP knows *exaclty* which *one* of five reasons people feel it is a "NARQ?"

Comment: That is already being explored here, albeit in a different way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv

Comment: **NARQ is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, rhetorical and cannot be comprehended in its current form.**

Comment: But I like to use it as a verb, like "I just NARQed (pronounced "narked") a bunch of questions." :P

Comment: 6) NARQ--because I say it is

Comment: Why would you want to have NARQ broken up? I can guarantee you if someone will complain about "why was this closed as NARQ?" they will do the same in a more specific "why was this closed as overly broad?"

Answer (score -3):

Well I think it is already pretty much self-explanatory.This question is either a question or not. Also this is currently an [opened debate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv) you can refer to it.

Let's take this question:

*I have a picture and I try to make it appear on screen. Now the picture is visible. But not on the screen. Just visible. I'm not sure how to show it.*

*What's wrong with my picture.*

- **Ambiguous -**

  > Open to more than one interpretation; having a double meaning.

*Did you mean the Visible property is true but you can't see it at runtime?*

- **Vague -**

  > Of uncertain, indefinite, or unclear character or meaning.

*You're not sure what to do or what you want? You should read a little about it first.*

- **Incomplete -**

  > Not having all the necessary or appropriate parts.

*Can we have some code? What picture?*

- **Overly Broad -**

  > Not limited or narrow; of extensive range or scope:

*With the provided information I can think of 100 possible solutions...I certainly won't write them all here and try to find the one that fits your particular case.*

Most of these points goes together I'm not sure if it's a good idea to split them. If it's not a question, it's simply *not a question* no matter what the specific reason is. What if you come accross a question that meets all of your new `NARQ specifications`? Which one will be predominent and why?

Comment: I dislike your example of overly broad.  In that case it's incomplete.  It couldn't be anything; there is likely just one thing, we just don't know enough to know what it is.  A better example would be something like, "How does Java manage memory".  You know enough to answer the question, it's just that answering it would take a book; it's too broad of a question to be able to cover everything in one SO answer.

Comment: @Servy I totally misread the question in the first place. I updated

Comment: "Well I think it is already pretty much self-explanatory.This question is either a question or not."  So, "can you do my homework for me?" or "How should I learn Java?" count as real questions?

Comment: @djechlin I meant the question either falls under the category not a real question, or it doesn't. Not about the fact that a question is a question if you put a `?` at the end. Simple enough ?

Comment: That's begging the question.  Someone says "can we clarify NARQ?" and you say "well if it falls under the category of a real question, then it is, or else it's not."  Your examples are fine but I downvoted because I don't think just asserting that it's clear enough (which I disagree with) and going through one example adds any value.

Comment: @djechlin Then maybe you should take the time to read until the end of the post where I actually make my point and say "No we don't need to clarify NARQ" :-)