# Old questions getting out of date and new questions get flagged as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, old-questions

Is there a discussion regarding questions and answers getting too old or inefficient?

Has any one else considered the risk of good, more valid, questions getting removed as duplicates, even though they could help the community more?

Comment: Probably: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47984/212576 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47962/212576

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on meta stack exchange, and it was flagged as a duplicate and merged with an "older" question:

[Can we be more specific as to why a question is "NARQ?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179326/can-we-be-more-specific-as-to-why-a-question-is-narq)

IMHO, this should not have been done. Not that the old question was "inefficient, but it already had 20-odd answers. Meaning that we should have started a new thread on a widely debated topic if the new question were at all different from the old one, because it could "help the community more." That is to say, the "default option" should have been in favor of having a new, separate question, rather than merging it with the old one as a "duplicate." (Unless the duplication was almost "total.")

Ironically, one of the answers to the "old" question was that an improved new question would focus on "technical details," and less on broad strokes, which is what my "new question" did. I would cite this as the "official" reason why the new question should have been left open, with the previous paragraph being the "real" reason.

Comment: @ Tom Au : so how do you think that one could avoide this removal. I mean, do the people that edit the questions really notice after a while what are they erasing? should you maybe be a person aware of the possible duplicate: maybe you first put a link in the body of the question to the original and then add a tag perhaps called "Revised territory" or something like that, so editors would pay more attention before they remove some potential vital data.

Comment: @noawithouth: These five people marked my answer as a duplicate. "marked as duplicate by sixlettervariables, LBT, Bart, Josh Caswell, Kate Gregory May 7 at 18:35"
You might want to ask them why, and try to persuade them otherwise. My recommendation was that the site should change its "mindset" so that the "default" option was "leave open" rather than "close." (But neither you nor I have nearly as much reputation on this site as the five others, and we might not carry much weight.) Thanks for your support.