# The ability to close questions should not be a community feature

Tags: feature-request, edits, vote-to-close

The ability to vote to close questions is too abusable. I feel like my legitimate questions have been closed due to some sort of conflict of interest and/or power trip. If I wanted my questions ignored I would have stayed on IRC or forums. I feel like this feature undermines the purpose of stack.

Things were fine with simple down-voting, in my opinion, and giving certain users the ability to also close my questions so that I never receive an answer makes just about as much sense as me voting to close the questions of those who closed my questions.

Comment: Do you have a specific change in mind, along with arguments to support your position, or would you like a review of your questions which have been closed? As this is now, it *seems* like a rant.

Comment: Really? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16301296/447356) shouldn't have been closed? I understand your frustration but ranting and whining are not the solution to anything.

Comment: It seems like the immediate downvoting of this post shows me everything I need to know about the direction stack is going in right now...

Comment: Andrew, yes. Please help me understand why this question was closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301296/can-i-search-google-for-only-businesses-with-virtual-tours

Comment: Why do you think that the search question is on-topic? It barely even mentions programming.

Comment: @Dewayne Ranting on MSO almost guarantees a rain of downvotes. The easy solution is: **Don't rant**. You _don't_ really have to, it _won't_ help, and there's always the risk that people will ignore a _legitimate_ concern because of the way you chose to raise it.

Comment: Because I'm asking if there is an API or anything at all which accomplishes what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Dewayne Stack Overflow is not for asking questions about everything you could possibly do with a computer or with the internet. It has a specific scope, and questions are expected to fall within that scope.

Comment: @Dewayne You can alert people you are talking to by typeing @ followed by their username.  Looking through your past comments, as well as the ones above, it didn't seem you were familiar with this feature.  If you already are, I apologize, but its the best way to get someone's attention as it sends a notification to them.

Comment: Patashu, asking an API question is outside of the scope of the google-api tag, and also, apparently off topic?

Comment: @Dewayne This is usually required, as people don't always stay staring at the same question for long; the people you are addressing may have already moved off onto another topic.

Comment: @Dewayne the question was tangentially an API question. I submitted edits to it to make it specific to the API and cast a vote to reopen.

Comment: As I watched this question progress, you were correct, there was a rain of downvotes since I worded the question in a ranty way. The interesting thing is that there are also a number of upvotes hidden in there as well. I suppose I should refrain from criticizing stackoverflow features within this site.

Comment: @Dewayne Feel free to criticize all you want, but please try to do it constructively. "Don't rant" doesn't mean don't have an opinion, or don't share that opinion.

Comment: Constructive criticism is fine. Rants are not.

Comment: @Yannis, I feel like requesting the removal of this feature is constructive criticism honestly.

Comment: "I feel like my legitimate questions have been closed due to some sort of conflict of interest and/or power trip" doesn't really fit my definition of constructive @Dewayne. Even if you strongly disagree with the closure, why not just assume it was accidental? Where do you base all the nonsense about power trips and conflicts of interest? Here's a couple of recent examples of constructive (imho) Meta questions about closed questions: [1](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1850) & [2](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5929)

Comment: At this point I refuse to criticize any feature within this site and will move my conversations about this elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)

Comment: @Dewayne Also be aware that votes on meta don't (nessissarily) mean you've worded it badly, it can just mean people disagree and want vote-to-close to stay. And I agree; it should stay. In fact the system worked in this case: The original post required considerable interpretation and was unclear. It was closed. The post was improved. It was reopened. This is exactly how the system is supposed to work

Comment: @Richard Actually it was clarified and re-opened and then closed again by moderators who were also commenters on this posting.

Comment: @Dewayne In that case it needs further improvement, as it currently stands it does beg the question "What have you tried". Look up the tutorials on the API, then come back with any problems. Remember; its SO's job to help you solve problems you face, not to teach you a particular technique. Thats what tutorials are for

Comment: This blog post makes some good points regarding "what have you tried" issues http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 13):

Something to consider: According to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67117/dewayne?tab=questions) now, you have a single question that was closed, out of 18. Compared to [my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber?tab=questions); out of 12, I have 2 closed, 1 marked duplicate, and 1 deleted.

I think you are doing fine.

On to your question that was closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301296/can-i-search-google-for-only-businesses-with-virtual-tours

The basic reasoning for the "Off Topic" close reason is that as you have presented it, it's not *specifically* a programing question. You seem to be asking, "How do I narrow my search criteria?", which could be something done programmatically, or via typing a search in a box.

However, it's also off-topic in a different way; As you note in the comments, your intent was to 'look for an API', which wasn't immediately obvious. However, *that* type of inquiry is also off-topic. (You'll also see such questions closed as Not Constructive, since they tend not to have a 'single, correct' answer.)

---

I can assure you that users do not close questions out of sheer malice here. Well, sometimes, someone might try to do that; but that's one reason closing requires 5 people of sufficient reputation (or one diamond moderator); so that someone can't just go on a closing spree just for the heck of it.

The closing system actually works more like an 'On Hold" system, to allow a question to be improved, then reopened. We have systems to make sure that happens, when appropriate. We're always improving it all, too; There are recent discussions here about how to improve the workflow and how it 'feels'.

Comment: Well ok, but I am actually asking a question related to the best approach for doing something. I assumed that people responding to my questions within those tags would understand that it is indeed a technical question as google has no "regular search" way of restricting a search to virtual tours. This is why I edited it to clarify that it was probably an API question but honestly I'm looking for an answer as to the best approach.

Comment: @Dewayne Any question with *best* in it is often a bad sign for a question. It worries people that it will become a gorilla vs shark  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Answer (score 3):

Your suggestion is completely impractical.

Stack Overflow receives a nearly constant stream of unsalvageable, off-topic, and even spammy questions. There are 16 diamond moderators. There's no way these guys (who aren't paid for their efforts, by the way) could keep up with that flood of garbage. If the only way to get posts closed was for these few volunteers and Stack Exchange's employees to do it, the site would quickly become as bad as Yahoo Answers.

The whole strength of the platform comes from offloading most of the moderation work to the community.

As for your last sentence, you're welcome to get 3000 site rep and with it the ability to cast 20% of the close votes you'll need for your sweet revenge. But the system isn't all that abusable; you'll need 4 other 3K rep people looking for revenge to punish the people who close your questions, and then another 5 to close them again when they're reopened. Good luck with that!

Comment: you had me at "Yahoo answers"

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you voted to re-close this question after it was rewritten by another moderator and re-opened.

Comment: I felt that even as edited, it reads a a "gimme the codez!" question, and 4 people agreed with me. In any case, is this meta question about one closure, or a suggestion to remove close voting altogether? If it's the latter, I don't see how your one closed question is particularly relevant; I'm sure you could find one of my 7000+ close votes that's more questionable.

Comment: @Dewayne Incidentally, your post was not edited by a moderator, but a regular user with editing privileges. The user tried to improve your question, but ultimately wasn't able to improve it enough.