# Having a question closed is frustrating for several reasons and the process should be improved

Tags: discussion

Just had a question closed.  The template text "This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." doesn't describe my question at all.  It is a specific question, which I would like a specific answer to.

Perhaps I phrased it poorly?  Perhaps the moderator is unfamiliar with the terminology so doesn't understand my question?  Doesn't matter.  It's been closed! No recourse, no explanation, nothing I can do.

The "helpful" FAQ is worse than useless, ie not informative and even more frustrating.

As far as I can tell, I can't even ask the person who closed it as to why they chose to do so.

Comment: If you are referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821129/what-are-the-foursquare-api-rules-about-returning-the-facebook-field-for-venue), I think you got your answer in your comments.  That is not a question, it is a request for Four Square to update their docs, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: all well and good but foursquare specifically uses stackoverflow for all their support interaction, and clicking on their"forum" link brings you to SO.  There are almost 1000 questions tagged for them here, so obviously SO has no problem with foursquare questions.

Comment: PS -- having my "weird noises" edited out was good for a chuckle.  :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv

Answer (score 16):

If you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821129/what-are-the-foursquare-api-rules-about-returning-the-facebook-field-for-venue), it was closed because you didn't actually ask a question we could answer.

Your question (literally) was:

> Please update the docs! Thanks

How can we answer that?

Looking at your question history, I'm seeing a few issues that (when resolved) may allow your closed questions to be reopened:

- Users should not have to visit external links to see the problem you're talking about. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846702/how-can-i-run-the-apple-storekit-in-the-simulator), you did just that:

  > I have written a blog post about the design decisions behind the code, which can be read here and includes a download link: http://code-evolution.blogspot.com/2010/05/evolved-code-example-1-simplestore-for.html
  >
  > Or you can just grab the sample project from this location: simplestoreevolved.googlecode.com/files/SimpleStoreEvolved.zip
- Your question should not be an answer. [it should only be a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925487/how-to-detect-iphone-app-state-changes). Write a separate answer if you want to answer your own question.
- Self promotion: Your questions have links to your blog posts that really don't need to be there. I'm not sure why those links are in your questions. This turns people off to your questions and can lead to closing. One user even commented:

  > I strongly recommend re-phrasing this as a true question, and then posting an answer, rather than trying to spam – [Mitchel Sellers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13279/mitchel-sellers) [Feb 7 '11 at 19:22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925487/how-to-detect-iphone-app-state-changes#comment5488753_4925487)
- Finally, rants.  Your newest question that I linked to in the beginning seems like a rant. If you clean up the post, properly format the links, and keep the emotion out of the post, that will help. Also, it seems like this question is a question for Foursquare, as it's about their API. If you make it more broad ("How can I do this using their API?") it would be better than "update your docs!".

Comment: Thats a reasonable response!  THANK YOU for pointing that out.  I was actually hoping for a reply explaining the situation AND would like them to update their reference page.  I will edit the question appropriately

Comment: George, isn't a "can someone answer my question" implied by any SO post?  The title of the post that was closed was 'What are the foursquare API rules about returning the “facebook” field for venues? ' which seems like a valid question.  To concentrate on the point that I also asked them to be clearer in their reference material seems a little picayune.

Comment: @softwareevolved Foursquare may have put their developer support on SO, but it's sort of like me telling you to tell my wife to stop pestering me when I'm on my computer.  You could certainly do that for me (especially if I gave you her Email address), but that's not the right way to handle it.  The right way is for me to stop being on my computer when my wife comes into the room. She is, after all, my wife, and deserves my full and complete attention.  My point is, there are things we can fix (Helping you to get the information from their API), and things we can't fix (Their documentation).

Comment: as I mentioned already, pointing out that my reference to their docs made my query less obvious, was exactly what I needed to know in order to improve my question.  My meta-post was that the current system could stand some improvement because the actual reasons for closing the question are (in my experience) never posted.  Just the template text which isn't very helpful.  Why not encourage or require a moderator to add a brief description about what was wrong with the question that resulted in its being closed?

Comment: She should really stop bothering you when you're on the computer. CAN'T SHE SEE YOU'RE ON THE COMPUTER?!?!?!

Comment: @softwareevolved When I woke up this morning, we had 537 flags in the moderator queue, and were seeing flags added at a rate of about 1 per minute.  If we as moderators left messages every single time we closed a question due to flags, we'd never have time to moderate.

Comment: LOL @DaveNewton  :)

Comment: @Dave That's when you're banned.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I refuse to believe that the very clever folks here couldn't figure out some mechanism to at least hint what the actual problem is.   Still laughing at dave's comment.  :)