# Why is this question closed with the specified reason?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

[WSDL validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152023/wsdl-validator)

A couple of useful answers and no flaming but still it is closed due to "this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion". That seems rather harsh, wat could be the reason the moderator did that?

Comment: Is there any code in the question? Does it ask to solve programming problem? No and No --> Off topic

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Some people here are very strict about the rules. IMO the correct answer would be the most 'helpful' answer. And given that many query this, I would keep it. Anyways, given the number of plainly bad questions which stay on SO, I would rather see a question like this stay due to its usefulness even though it breaks the strict rule.

Comment: @SaintHill - Closed just means no new answers can be added. It doesn't mean we're going to delete it. I support keeping it closed because all these do is attract spam, but I'd argue for keeping it undeleted because the answers that are there may arguably add value. Hope this helps!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help us make "Not Constructive" and "Not a Real Question" closures more effective](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171732/help-us-make-not-constructive-and-not-a-real-question-closures-more-effectiv)

Answer (score 19):

Modern version:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite
>   off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to
>   attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem
>   and what has been done so far to solve it.

Notice how all of the answers to that question are effectively link only answers, will any of the answers to that question be useful without the links?

Link only answers generally rot over time as those sites may go down, change locations, etc. On SO it is required that answers be able to stand on their own, links may be used for reference, but the answer must still be helpful without them.

Pretty much every answer to this type of question will consist of a link to the answer's "favorite" offsite resource or personal site that has something to do with the question asked. Given that each answerer is promoting their "favorite" they often start to quibble over which is really the "best", which leads to a lot of noise and distraction from the site's primary purpose.

To sum up, recommendation questions are a bad fit for SO because they only attract answers that are a bad fit for SO, and usually generate a lot of non-constructive discussion.

Answer (score 13):

It was rightly closed, but the old reason wasn't as specific as the new close reason.

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

I reopened it and closed it for the more specific reason.

Comment: Would a historical lock make sense?

Comment: If you wanted to even go historical locking you may as well first delete the three duplicate answers

Answer (score 1):

Your question is asking for a list of things. In this case a list of libraries that provide a certain set of functionalities.

Questions asking for a list of things are off topic at Stack Overflow. Three people who voted to close the question were correct to close it, but they chose the wrong reason.

Comment: It's not the OPs question... and the close reason is the old one used for this sort of question. Otherwise, yes...